# Сослаться на несколько Node через $

Tags: jquery

Есть такие переменные:

```
var  
article = $('body wrapper article'),
section = $('body wrapper section');
```

Как, используя эти две переменные, сослаться на обе сразу?
Хочу типа такого:
`$(article, section).click(function(){//...});`, но не работает такой способ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `merge`

```
$.merge(article, section).click(...)
```

Можно использовать `add`

```
artilce.add(section).click(...)
```